# Insert in postgres DB - Hindi

Tags: java, postgresql, multilingual

I am creating a Java application where I would like to enter data in languages other then English. E.g. I want to enter data in Hindi (UTF-8) character. I have converted the data to hex string `'\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x97\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95'`

However, when I try to transform the data back to Hindi using `convert_from` I'm getting the below error:

```
select convert_from('\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x97\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95', 'UTF8') aa
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal digit: "\"
LINE 1: select convert_from('\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x97\xe...
                            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid hexadecimal digit: "\"
SQL state: 22023
Character: 21
```

I am using Postgres.

Comment: try using \\ or //

Comment: try to escape '\' by using '\\'

Comment: tried but it didnt convert hex codes to my Hindi text

Comment: In Denmark and Norway we use the letters æ, ø and å. I can save text directly to postgres, like "insert into foo(food) values ('blåbærsyltetøj');" (blueberry jam) as long as the database have the same encoding as the text inserted. In my case I use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options. If your database is already in UTF8 (and the client encoding is also UTF8), just use the [**E**scape literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE):

```
select E'\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x97\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95'
```

Use the `convert_from()` & the escape literals when your database is not UTF8 (but your client encoding is UTF8):

```
select convert_from(E'\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x97\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95', 'UTF8')
```

Use `convert_from()` & `decode()` with simple literals when neither your database, nor your client encoding is UTF8:

```
convert_from(decode('e0a4a8e0a4bee0a497e0a4b0e0a4bfe0a495', 'hex'), 'UTF8')
```

http://rextester.com/SPGFDP50612

*I have converted the data to hex string* -- Anyway, these problems shouldn't arise when you use prepared statements & bind your original data as a parameter for it. Your language's bindings should handle the conversions, instead of you.

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me will try using prepared statement as well

Answer (score 0):

1. Yum install  *hindi* on centos7
2. install postgres 9 or 10 any release
3. create table aayurved( utpaad char(41),sankhya char(5),mishran1 char(40),mishran2 char(41));
4. insert into aayurved values('देताबेस',0,'लोकिनग','सेशन');